# Qt implicitly-shared container of explicitly-shared item

Tags: qt, memory-management

I created a class `Foo` that is explicitly shared. In my program I have a data member `QVector<Foo> data;` that I pass around between different classes by reference to optimize memory usage.

During runtime, an object might change a specific element of `data`. For example:

```
Foo item = data.at(0);
item.setName("newName");
```

I would like to know if a new vector is deeply copied because of a COW or is it just that `Foo` object at location `0` changed its name only?

Answer (score 1):

In your example `item` contains a copy of the `Foo` item at position 0 in `data`. This is because `QVector::at()` returns a const reference and the `=` says to copy it into `item`.

If you had:

```
Foo & item = data[0];
item.setName("newName"); // <--- typo of single quotes here in your version
```

The `Foo` item at position 0 in the QVector would now have the name "newName" because in this example, `item` is a reference and the QVector operators `[]` return a non-const reference to the actual `Foo`.

Comment: Thank you for the typo hint :)
I think you are right, the at() function returns a const reference, so operator[] should be used instead to be able to modify the element.
However this is making me more confused, because I thought if an element of container is modified a new copy of the vector will be created. Am I correct?

Comment: That depends on whether the reference you have to the QVector is const or non-const.